# Working with currency in knockout & javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, globalization

In my application I have an form which has some fields for money. I have some also an knockout's customBinding to handle input and add correct currency sign for inserted value (example: 55 -> $55 | 55€).

Problem starts when currency sign had to be after inserted value. Then in case when somebody insert some value and then click Backspace to my KO binding goes wrong value.

**Example**

My currency is €. I insert '123' to my input and my binding change it to '123€'. Then I click Backspace and value which I have in my binding is '123' instead of '12€' or '12'. So I have problem to get to know how output value should looks.

Is there an solution for this problem? I thought about handling Backspace key or make some comparission with currency symbols, but maybe somebody know better solution for this?

Comment: where is your custom binding

Comment: have you tried valueUpdate:afterKeyPress

Comment: @raheelshan I have used 'valueUpdate' attribute. I think my custom binding isn't issue in this case because this situation is common, normal behaviour and I only search for solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)

```
ko.extenders.currency = function(target, options) {
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target, 
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target();
            if((''+newValue).indexOf(options.currencySymbol) == -1){
            if (options.position == 'left') {
                target(options.currencySymbol+newValue);
            } else {
                target(newValue+options.currencySymbol);
            }}
        }
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

    result(target());

    return result;
};

function AppViewModel(one, two) {
    this.myNumberOne = ko.observable(one).extend({ currency: { currencySymbol : '£', position : 'left'}});
    this.myNumberTwo = ko.observable(two).extend({ currency: { currencySymbol : '£', position : 'right'}});
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(221.2234, 123.4525));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw7wq/1/)

Comment: Issue is much more complex, I've just show concrete problem